# WP8 Gzip compression

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone-8, gzip

WP8 does not support Gzip compression, but there is 3rd party libraries that will allow you do so, i have tried many but i am not able to make it work. this is my latest try:

var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

```
        if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
        {
            handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip |
                                             DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        }

        Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.web.com");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

        client.BaseAddress = myUri;

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ubq-compression", "gzip");

        HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, myUri);
        req.Content = new StringContent(finalURL, Encoding.UTF8);

        HttpResponseMessage rm = client.SendAsync(req).Result;
        string rst = await rm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

the API return to me an array of bytes but the the first 300 are not Gziped but everything else is

i need to unzip everything that comes after the 300 bytes.

i am using the http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http

// i am splitting the array 
byte[] hJ = res.Take(300).ToArray();
byte[] bJ = res.Skip(300).ToArray();

bj is what need to be decompressed.

i am trying this

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                    stream.Write(bj, 0, bj.Length);

```
                using (var inStream = new MemoryStream(bj)) 
                {
                    var bigStreamsss = new GZipStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);

                    using (var bigStreamOut = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        bigStreamsss.CopyTo(bigStreamOut);
                        output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bigStreamOut.ToArray(), 0, bigStreamOut.ToArray().Length);
                    }

                }
```

but it is always failing on this line "
                        var bigStreamsss = new GZipStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
"

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the compression header there's nothing you need to do. The server compresses and the client decompresses automatically and you don't have to worry about anything. However it sounds like you're using some proprietary content compression standard where you only compress some of it. If that's the case don't mess with any compression settings on the http client, and instead use a 3rd party uncompress library. Just seek 300 bytes on the response stream, then pass that stream to the library. You should be able to use my inflater from my gzip library, that you can find here: https://github.com/dotMorten/SharpGIS.GZipWebClient/blob/master/src/SharpGIS.GZipWebClient/GZipDeflateStream.cs
It's extremely light-weight (it's just this one file). First call

myResultStream.Seek(300, SeekOrigin.Begin);

If the stream isn't seekable, you will need to read the first 300 bytes first though.
Then use my class to decompress the rest:

Stream gzipStream = new SharpGIS.GZipInflateStream(myResultStream);

You can now read the gzipStream as if it was an uncompressed stream.

However I really don't understand why you don't use standard http compression and let the server compress everything including the first 300 bytes. It's much easier and better for the all the kittens out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.componentace.com/zlib_.NET.htm library (available through nuget):

part of request handler:

```
            try {
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
                using (var response = request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult))
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
                    bool zip = false;
                    if (response.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Content-Encoding") &&
                        response.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding].ToLower() == "gzip") zip = true;
                    using (var reader = zip ?
#if NETFX_CORE
                        new StreamReader(new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
#else
                        new StreamReader(new zlib.ZOutputStream(stream), false)
#endif
                        : new StreamReader(stream)) {
                        var str = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        result = new ObjectResult(str);
                    }
                }
            } 
catch (WebException e) {...}
```

Comment: the library is does not support windows phone 8

Comment: this library support even portable library. the sample (above) part of wp7 project.